# High performance WebView for older Devices as Library?

Tags: android, html, webview, chromium

for the last months I developed several HTML5 Apps with Cordova.
Cause I saw some performance struggles on some devices I used the Crosswalk plugin.
Crosswalk adds a standalone chromium version to cordova so the HTML5 app (mostly a game) will open in the more powerfull webview.

Now I want to build a native Adnroid Library (aar) with an API so other developers cann just call a function and a new webview (or activity with an webview) will appear so the user can play the game. So this has nothing to do with Cordova, at all.

**The question:**
Does someone know some kind of "crosswalk" for a native a android project?
The best solution would be something like another aar which I can hook into the project :)

Thanks in advance
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Okay! I am a bit stupid.
The answere is also Croswalk!
I thougth this is only for Cordova/Phonegap.

[Here](https://diego.org/2015/01/07/embedding-crosswalk-in-android-studio/) you can find how to implement crosswalk with a simple native Android application!

I just downloaded a crowwalk aar and imported it to Android Studio.